# PayPal Express Checkout with IE9

Tags: paypal, internet-explorer-9

I get an error with this that stops the PayPal button from rendering.

In the `checkout.js` file (which specifies `paypalincontextjs @version 3.4.1 @timestamp 01-14-2016` at the top), there is a function at line 587:

```
function _nao() {
    var perfNow = window.performance && window.performance.now();
    var now = parseInt(perfNow || new Date().getTime(), 10);
    return now;
}
```

IE's F12 Developer Tools console reports that "Object doesn't support property or method 'now'".

Has anybody else encountered this? Can anybody suggest a work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is now fixed.
Version 3.4.2 of checkout.js now has

`var perfNow = window.performance && window.performance.now && window.performance.now();`

on line 587, and so works in IE9.